# Code that works, but makes little sense to me: if str1.find("not")

Tags: python

New to coding/Python and doing codingbat challenges. Really basic stuff.

https://codingbat.com/prob/p189441

^ This problem can be solved writing:

```
def not_string(str1):
    if str1.find("not"):
        return "not " + str1
    else:
        return str1
```

This doesn't make much sense to me. If you write "candy" it adds "not " to it, which is what the challenge wanted, but.. uh, how? The find command surely didn't find "not" in the string, so it should skip to the else clause? This is how I would want to solve it:

```
 def not_string(str1):
    if str1.find("not") == 0:  # If string begins with "not"
        # ^ Gives index position of substring as value (-1 if not found)
        return str1
    else:  # If string doesn't begin with "not"
        return "not " + str1
```

Everything in the second example makes perfect sense to me, but the first example is scary voodoo to me. Can someone explain?

Comment: I remember also getting very confused when seeing something like `if myVar` for the first time. My first impression was: if myVar what? there's no comparison to anything for the if to evaluate if myVar is true or false. So probably is also what happens here. You don't need to do `if myVar != 0` a simple `if myVar` will work, since 0 evaluates to false and non-zero evaluates to true

Comment: A better and more explicit code: `return str1 if str1.startswith('not') else f'not {str1}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`str1.find("not")` returns the index of the substring, if it is found; and -1 if it is not found.

If you use it as a condition:

```
if str1.find("not"):
```

then it will only be falsey if `str1.find("not")` returns zero, because all ints are truthy except for zero.

You can read it as:

```
if str1.find("not") != 0:
```

For example:

- if `str1` is `"alpha"` (a string not containing `"not"`), then `str1.find("not")` returns -1, and so the condition succeeds.
- if `str1` is `"beta not"` (a string containing `"not"` but not starting with it), then `str1.find("not")` returns a string greater than zero, and so the condition succeeds.
- if `str1` is `"not gamma"` (a string starting with `"not"`), then `str1.find("not")` returns zero, and so the condition **fails**.

Therefore

```
if str1.find("not"):
```

is equivalent (inefficiently) to

```
if not str1.startswith("not"):
```

See [str.find](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find), [str.startswith](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.startswith).

Answer (score 0):

`std.find` method does the following (check out [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.find))

> Return the lowest **index** in the string where substring sub is found within the slice s[start:end]. Optional arguments start and end are interpreted as in slice notation. Return -1 if sub is not found.

For your task it means, that if the string already begins with `not`, then `.find` will return 0, and Python will interpret 0 as `False`, falling back to the `else` branch. If `not` is somewhere in the string, a positive number is returned, and if `not` is missing, -1 is returned, and Python will interpret those numbers as `True`, leading to the main branch of `if`